# Problema al obtener datos de JComboBox Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Java y quiero obtener la información de un JTextField y un JComboBox ya los genere en el Jframe el problema es que estoy tratando de obtener su contenido a travez de un metodo y me marca el error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class pruebas extends JFrame {
    static String[] lista = { "RUTEO", "ESTATICO","BGP" };
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static String[][][] ValueTypes;
    static JComboBox combo_rutmen;
    static JTextField tf_REFERENCIA;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pruebas frame = new pruebas();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public pruebas() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    ValueTypes = new String[3][50][4];

    JComboBox combo_rutmen = new JComboBox(lista);
    combo_rutmen.setBounds(128, 63, 78, 20);
    contentPane.add(combo_rutmen);

    JButton btnMerge = new JButton("Merge");
    btnMerge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            combo();
        }
    });
    btnMerge.setBounds(190, 228, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnMerge);

    JTextField tf_REFERENCIA = new JTextField();
    tf_REFERENCIA.setText("a32");
    tf_REFERENCIA.setBounds(128, 94, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_REFERENCIA);
    tf_REFERENCIA.setColumns(10);
}

static  void combo() {
    System.out.println("REFERENCIA " + tf_REFERENCIA.getText());
    System.out.println("Ruteo " + combo_rutmen.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
}
```

El error es generado al momento de dar clic en el botón Merge

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at pruebas.combo(pruebas.java:67)   at
>   pruebas$2.actionPerformed(pruebas.java:54)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class pruebas extends JFrame {
    ...
    static JComboBox combo_rutmen;
    static JTextField tf_REFERENCIA;
    ...
    public pruebas() {
       JComboBox combo_rutmen = new JComboBox(lista);
       ...
       JTextField tf_REFERENCIA = new JTextField();
       ...
    }

    static  void combo() {
       System.out.println("REFERENCIA " + tf_REFERENCIA.getText());
       System.out.println("Ruteo " + combo_rutmen.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
```

El problema es que lo que hace tu código es definir unas variables `combo_rutmen` y `tf_REFERENCIA` que son **locales al método `pruebas()`** y que ocultan la definición de las variables "globales". Cuando haces la asignación, lo haces a una variable que no es la que tienes definida en la clase, y que deja de existir tan pronto sales del método.

Por eso, cuando ejecutas `combo()` (que sí usa las variables "globales"), se encuentra con que éstas no han sido inicializadas y tienes el `NullPointerException`.

Solución: asigna a las variables, sin declarar otras nuevas.

```
 public pruebas() {
    ...
    combo_rutmen = new JComboBox(lista);
```

Una forma de asegurarte de que no usas variables locales (por ejemplo, si te has despistado y has llamado otra variable local igual) es indicar su *scope* cada vez que las usas. En el caso de variables estáticas, el nombre de la clase:

```
    pruebas.combo_rutmen = new JComboBox(lista);
```

; en el caso de variables de instancia, **this**:

```
    this.combo_rutmen = new JComboBox(lista);
```

Un par de apuntes no relacionados, pero importantes:

- Donde no sea necesario, hay que evitar métodos y atributos `static`. Aquí no hay ninguna necesidad de hacer que las variables o `combo` sean `static`. Los elementos `static` no casan bien con la programación orientada a objetos.
- Revisa la documentación de nomenclatura de Java (nombres de clases empiezan por mayúscula, variables y métodos en *camel_case*). Una vez acostumbrado ayuda a leer el código, y a la vez se hace difícil y extraño leer que el nombre de la clase es `pruebas` y no `Pruebas`, por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por el apoyo, estuve revisando y como dices las variables se estaban ocultando.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class pruebas extends JFrame {
    static String[] lista = { "RUTEO", "ESTATICO","BGP" };
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static JComboBox combo_rutmen = new JComboBox(lista);
    static JTextField tf_REFERENCIA = new JTextField();
    private final JButton btnColoca = new JButton("COLOCA");
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    pruebas frame = new pruebas();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public pruebas() {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);


    combo_rutmen.setBounds(128, 63, 78, 20);
    contentPane.add(combo_rutmen);

    JButton btnMerge = new JButton("Merge");
    btnMerge.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            combo();
        }
    });
    btnMerge.setBounds(35, 120, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnMerge);


    tf_REFERENCIA.setText("a32");
    tf_REFERENCIA.setBounds(128, 94, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(tf_REFERENCIA);
    tf_REFERENCIA.setColumns(10);
    btnColoca.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            combo_rutmen.setSelectedIndex(1);
        }
    });
    btnColoca.setBounds(138, 120, 89, 23);

    contentPane.add(btnColoca);
}

static  void combo() {
    System.out.println("REFERENCIA " + pruebas.tf_REFERENCIA.getText());
    System.out.println("Ruteo " + pruebas.combo_rutmen.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
}
```

lo que hice fue quitar la definición del objeto que estaba dentro de prueba y los puse sobre

public class pruebas extends JFrame {

intenten como me recomendaste quitarles el atributo de static pero me seguía marcando error eclipse me daba como ayuda volverlo a poner para que se arreglara de esta forma al fin pude leer el contenido de los objetos y gracias por los comentarios extra me pondré a aplicarlos como me lo comentas.

saludos