# Duda de java trabajando con superclases y subclases

Tags: java

Una pregunta con respecto a un trabajo que estoy haciendo en java. Resulta que tengo la siguiente parte de una superclase:

```
public abstract class Jugador {
    private String nombre;
    private int cantVidas;
    private int nivelActual;

    public Jugador(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        cantVidas=3;
        nivelActual=0;
    }
```

También están sus getters y setters correspondientes a cada variable.
Tengo una subclase que se llama "Principiante", mi pregunta es: ¿Puedo hacer el siguiente método en esta subclase?

```
public void pasarDeNivel(){
    int nivel;
    nivel = getNivelActual();
    nivel = nivel + 1;
}
```

y después hacer un método que te imprima el nivel. y que te quede que el nivel ahora es 1.

Tengo el problema que siempre voy a tener la variable "nivel" en 0, nunca se incrementa a 1.

Comment: `nivel` es una **variable local**. Más información https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/89928/problema-al-obtener-datos-de-jcombobox-java/89935#89935

Comment: Esto pasa por que lo que haces es que copias con el método getNivelActual() el valor del nivel, y no estas usando el setter para actualizar ese valor, recuerda que en java los tipos primitivos(int, float, char) se pasan por valor y no por referencia como lo hacen las clases.

Comment: Claro, genial, muchas gracias por responder!

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que `nivel` es una variable local, lo q deberias es modificar la variable `nivelActual` de la clase `Jugador` con tu metodo modificador. tu metodo quedaria asi:

```
public void pasarDeNivel(){
    setNivelActual(getNivelActual()+1); //le pasas el nivel actual + 1
}
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Una pregunta, me podes describir otra forma de sumarle +1 a getNivelActual, utilizando el mismo metodo "pasarDeNivel()"?

Comment: la otra es almacenar en una variable y luego sumarle, `int nivel=getNivelActual()+1; setNivelActual(nivel);` pero no veo la necesidad de crear esta variable